# C# app on Task Scheduler keeps running without executing code

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I have a c# program which runs fine when debugged/ran from VS. When it runs on the task scheduler it stops at a certain point in my code and just runs and runs. I can see this based on my logs.

Here's my code:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Log.WriteLog("Email Sync invoking...");

            // task scheduler stops here
            foreach (EmailAccount account in EmailAccount.Get())
            {
                Log.WriteLog("Syncing email account " + account.Username);
                EmailAccount.Sync(12, account.Username);
            }

            Log.WriteLog("Email Sync completed.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: This would indicate to me that something is going on inside EmailAccount.Get() which suspends execution (such as a lock) or goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: @GeneS but it works fine when run from VS. Also that method currently brings up only 3 records. What gives?

Comment: Under which account runs program when is invoked by TaskScheduler?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan the task is running under my account.

Comment: I would recommend adding some logging in your EmailAccount.Get() and see if it is executing that code and, if so, where does it get stuck there.

Comment: @GeneS It's getting stuck when executing the query to the DB, but not sure why.

Comment: More info: I specify the connection string in my app.config (which is in the same folder as my exe) and my code gets it with ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings. When I check "run with highest privileges", I get a "network-related or instance-specific" error.

Comment: Is your SQL Server database on another server?  Is your connection string using a trusted connection?  If both of these are true then you need to make sure your task is running under a domain user account (in the General tab of the task) and that domain user needs to have access to your database.  Another approach is to use a SQL Server account in your connection string instead of a windows account.

Comment: @GeneS I played around with the user account - changed it to Admistrators, then back to my account and bingo - it worked! And I am already using a SQL Server account in my connection string... So that's strange, but glad it's working now. I'm going to wait and see if it continues to work. I'll let you know sooner or later. Thank you.